# Set default value of Javascript object attributes

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to set the default attribute of a Javascript object such that:

```
let emptyObj = {};
// do some magic
emptyObj.nonExistingAttribute // => defaultValue
```

Comment: EVERY non existing attribute or just a KNOWN attribute name?

Comment: `let o = new Proxy({}, { get: (o, k) => k in o ? o[k] : 'some default value' }; console.log(o.key1)`

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy your proposal deserve to be a proper answer. If JS do not provide default value for properties, Proxy is clearly the nicest approach !

Answer (score 184, accepted):

*Since I asked the question several years ago things have progressed nicely.*

Proxies are part of ES6. The following example works in [Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Proxy):

```
let handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    return target.hasOwnProperty(name) ? target[name] : 42;
  }
};

let emptyObj = {};
let p = new Proxy(emptyObj, handler);

p.answerToTheUltimateQuestionOfLife; //=> 42
```

---

Read more in [Mozilla's documentation on Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: If you are planning to support Internet Explorer (before Edge), you're out of luck:
http://caniuse.com/#search=proxy

Also, polyfill https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect doesn't support IE

Comment: Congrats, you've earned _Phoenix_ (Gold Badge: answered one of your own questions at least a year later, with an answer that at least doubled the number of votes of the most popular answer)

Comment: Object.withDefault=(defaultValue,o={})=>new Proxy(o,{get:(o,k)=>(k in o)?o[k]:defaultValue});
    
    o=Object.withDefault(42);

    o.x  //=> 42

    o.x=10

    o.x  //=> 10

    o.xx  //=> 42

Comment: So using Proxy also means `Object.getEntries` can't be called on a Proxy :(

Comment: If you mean `Object.entries`, you can modify the handler to set properties when they are accessed. Change `return target.hasOwnProperty(name) ? target[name] : 42;` to `if (!target.hasOwnProperty(name)) target[name] = 42; return target[name];`.

Comment: That's what i was looking for. I remember i've read about this functionality in the past but i couldn't remember how it was used and what was the method. But yeah i think proxy is the most clean way of doing that. It will only cause issues if Internet Explorer is used but i guess it can be pollyfilled

Comment: This answer is cool, but I think its not good to specify the default value in the handler. I think its more usefull to return null instead (or undefined) like this ` return target.hasOwnProperty(name) ? target[name] : null;` then you can assign stuff with default values like this: `p.answerToTheUltimateQuestionOfLife ?? 42`.  This is usefull if you have a data object with multiple properties.

Answer (score 66):

Use *destructuring* (new in ES6)

There is great [documentation by Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as well as a fantastic [blog post](http://wesbos.com/destructuring-default-values/) that explains the syntax better than I can.

#### To Answer Your Question

```
var emptyObj = {};
const { nonExistingAttribute = defaultValue } = emptyObj;
console.log(nonExistingAttribute); // defaultValue
```

#### Going Further

Can I **rename** this variable? Sure!

```
const { nonExistingAttribute: coolerName = 15} = emptyObj;
console.log(coolerName); // 15
```

What about nested data? Bring it on!

```
var nestedData = {
    name: 'Awesome Programmer',
    languages: [
        {
            name: 'javascript',
            proficiency: 4,
        }
    ],
    country: 'Canada',
};

var {name: realName, languages: [{name: languageName}]} = nestedData ;

console.log(realName); // Awesome Programmer
console.log(languageName); // javascript
```

Comment: What is this code doing and what has it got to do with default values?

Comment: This is a really good answer with examples for setting defaults on missing keys, which is precisely what the OP asked for. To answer the question above, line 12 with var {name: realName... is only missing a default value, at most. You are being unfairly harsh to the author.

Answer (score 30):

There isn't a way to set this in Javascript - returning `undefined` for non-existent properties is a part of the core Javascript spec. See [the discussion for this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511542/force-javascript-exception-error-when-reading-an-undefined-object-property). As I suggested there, one approach (though I can't really recommend it) would be to define a global `getProperty` function:

```
function getProperty(o, prop) {
    if (o[prop] !== undefined) return o[prop];
    else return "my default";
}

var o = {
    foo: 1
};

getProperty(o, 'foo'); // 1
getProperty(o, 'bar'); // "my default"
```

But this would lead to a bunch of non-standard code that would be difficult for others to read, and it might have unintended consequences in areas where you'd expect or want an undefined value. Better to just check as you go:

```
var someVar = o.someVar || "my default";
```

Comment: warning: `var someVar = o.someVar || "my default";` will have potentially unexpected results when o.someVar is populated but evaluates to false (e.g. null, 0, ""). `someVar = o.someVar === undefined ? o.someVar : "my default";` would be better. I typically use `||` alone when the default also evaluates to `false. (e.g. `o.someVar || 0`)

Comment: That's a good point - this won't work anywhere where a false-y value is valid input, and you have to consider that when using this pattern. But more often than not, it makes sense to treat a property explicitly set to `null` or `false` in the same way as an unset property, in which case this does double duty. The warning is fair, though.

Comment: @Shanimal Your example is the wrong way around, it should be `someVar = o.someVar === undefined ? "my default" : o.someVar;`, only a minor issue but it threw me for a little bit when I first tried your code ;-)

Comment: yes @Metalskin we wouldn't care for the undefined value would we? lol. sorry, hopefully the mistake didn't cost you too much time :)

Answer (score 19):

This seems to me the most simple and readable way of doing so:

```
let options = {name:"James"}
const default_options = {name:"John", surname:"Doe"}

options = Object.assign({}, default_options, options)
```

[Object.assign() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: I was going to answer that underscore library has _.defaults(object, *defaults) method for that, but your answer get the same without any library!

Comment: This is now the solution I like best.

Answer (score 17):

my code is:

```
function(s){
    s = {
        top: s.top || 100,    // default value or s.top
        left: s.left || 300,  // default value or s.left
    }
    alert(s.top)
}
```

Comment: I like this solution the best, because it is similar to what I do in PHP.  `function foo( array $kwargs = array() )
{
  // Fill in defaults for optional keyworded arguments.
  $kwargs += array(
    'show_user' => true,
    'show_links' => false,
  );  ...`

Comment: And what if 's' will be undefined (i.e. not specified at all)?

Comment: @didzis You could do `function(s = {})` which would fix the not filling it in at all. But you could also add this on the first line of the function: `s = s || {}` to fix not filling it and also fix `null` or `undefined` as parameters. You could also inline that, but I that's definitely not recommended: `top: (s || {}).top || 100`

Comment: what if s.top is zero, then what's the result in that case

Answer (score 15):

The way I achieve this is with the `object.assign` function

```
const defaultProperties = { 'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'foo' };
const overwriteProperties = { 'foo': 'foo' };
const newObj = Object.assign({}, defaultProperties, overwriteProperties);
console.log(defaultProperties);  // {"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}
console.log(overwriteProperties);  // { "foo": "foo" };
console.log(newObj);  // { "foo": "foo", "bar": "foo" }
```

Comment: Doing this you are also overwriting the values of `overwriteProperties` the correct way is: `const newObj = Object.assign({}, defaultProperties, overwriteProperties)`

Answer (score 11):

This sure sounds like the typical use of protoype-based objects:

```
// define a new type of object
var foo = function() {};  

// define a default attribute and value that all objects of this type will have
foo.prototype.attribute1 = "defaultValue1";  

// create a new object of my type
var emptyObj = new foo();
console.log(emptyObj.attribute1);       // outputs defaultValue1
```

Comment: if you call console.log(emptyObj), it return {}. not { attribute1 : 'defaultValue1' }

Comment: Yes, because `attribute1: defaultValue1` is on the prototype and console.log only enumerates items set on the top level object, not on the prototype.  But, the value is there as my `console.log(emptyObj.attribute1)` shows.

Comment: it's right but it the same problem with `JSON.stringify(emptyobj)`. I was forced to create a method that returns all the attributes in response to this problem

Answer (score 8):

Or you can try this

```
dict = {
 'somekey': 'somevalue'
};

val = dict['anotherkey'] || 'anotherval';
```

Comment: Bad idea if dict['anotherkey'] is 0.

Comment: Maybe you should consider this: http://www.codereadability.com/javascript-default-parameters-with-or-operator/

Comment: @RayToal Then wouldn't `String()` fix that? As in:
`val = dict[String('anotherkey')] || 'anotherval';`

Comment: No, sorry, it would not. Same problem. Try it: First do `d = {x: 1, y: 0}` then `d['y'] || 100` and not it erroneously gives 100. Then try your idea which is `d[String('y')] || 100` -- it _still_ improperly gives 100 when it should give 0.

Answer (score 8):

I think the simplest approach is using `Object.assign`.

If you have this Class:

```
class MyHelper {
    constructor(options) {
        this.options = Object.assign({
            name: "John",
            surname: "Doe",
            birthDate: "1980-08-08"
        }, options);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let helper = new MyHelper({ name: "Mark" });
console.log(helper.options.surname); // this will output "Doe"
```

Documentation (with polyfill):
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 8):

**Simplest of all Solutions:**

```
dict = {'first': 1,
        'second': 2,
        'third': 3}
```

Now,

```
dict['last'] || 'Excluded'
```

will return 'Excluded', which is the default value.

Comment: this fails if you have a slightly different dict:
`dict = {'first': 0,
        'second': 1,
        'third': 2}`

Comment: This is also a great way to chain values that might not exist. For example `a.b.c.d`. If a, d, or c are undefined you hit an error, but you can just do `(((a || {}).b || {}).c || {}).d) || "default"`

Comment: This is great and the simplest. One improvement I've made is to put the default value inside the dict object itself, so `dict[key] || dict.default` :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you only have an object that is a **single level deep** (nested object properties will not merge as expected since it directly destructures from the first level), you can use the following destructuring syntax:

```js
const options = {
    somevar: 1234,
    admin: true
};

const defaults = {
    test: false,
    admin: false,
};

var mergedOptions = {...defaults, ...options};
```

Of which the output would be:

```js
console.log(options);
// { somevar: 1234, admin: true }

console.log(mergedOptions);
// { test: false, admin: true, somevar: 1234 }
```

Or even formatted as a single statement (this is slightly unreadable though):

```js
const options = {...{
    // Defaults
    test: false,
    admin: false,
}, ...{
    // Overrides
    somevar: 1234,
    admin: true
}};
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw an article yesterday that mentions an `Object.__noSuchMethod__` property: [JavascriptTips](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips#No_Such_Method_%28_noSuchMethod_%29) I've not had a chance to play around with it, so I don't know about browser support, but maybe you could use that in some way?

Comment: Saw that page too, we must have read the same HN article. Only methods though. It could be done with __defineGetter__ but that isn't in ECMA5 unfortunately. They wen't with another getter/setter approach that is worse in my view (requires definition of properties beforehand).

Comment: This could be an answer in the future :) Let's hope browsers will get there soon :) ♬

Comment: I believe the future answer will be to use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: @JamesLong yes, you are correct! turns out the future has arrived :) 3 years after I asked the question this now works in FF (and other browsers soon). I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned ternary operator yet.

```
var emptyObj = {a:'123', b:'234', c:0};
var defaultValue = 'defaultValue';
var attr = 'someNonExistAttribute';
emptyObj.hasOwnProperty(attr) ? emptyObj[attr] : defaultValue;//=> 'defaultValue'


attr = 'c'; // => 'c'
emptyObj.hasOwnProperty(attr) ? emptyObj[attr] : defaultValue; // => 0
```

In this way, even if the value of 'c' is 0, it will still get the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {
  a: 2,
  b: 4
};

console.log(obj);

--> {a: 2, b: 4}

function applyDefaults(obj) {
  obj.a ||= 10;
  obj.b ||= 10;
  obj.c ||= 10;
}

// do some magic
applyDefaults(obj);

console.log(obj);

--> {a: 2, b: 4, c: 10}
```

This works because

```
undefined || "1111111" --> "1111111"
"0000000" || "1111111" --> "0000000"
```

as `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, `""` (Empty String), `false` itself, are all considered to be equivalent to false ([falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)). Anything else is `true` ([truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)).

Note that this is not uniformly supported across browsers and nodejs versions (confirm for yourself).

So two troublesome cases are the empty String `""` and `0` (zero). If it is important not to override those, you might need to rewrite this as:

```
if (typeof obj.d == "undefined") obj.d = "default"
```

This will be better supported across browsers also.

Alternatively you could write this as:

```
obj.d ??= "default"
```

This is the [nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) which applies only to values that are `null` or `undefined` ([nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish)) - of which the empty string is *not* part. However, this has again a diminished cross-browser support.

See also on the official Mozilla Website - [Assigning a default value to a variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#assigning_a_default_value_to_a_variable).

Comment: I find it beneficial that this logical OR assignment can be used to initialize a property and to subsequently refer to it also, nesting such references infinitely: 
((document['myLog']||={}).lines||=[]).push('possibly first')

Comment: Node just does not support the operator yet, so I had to work it around clumsily:

function orAssign(o, key, def) {
  return o[key] || (o[key]=def)
}

Comment: @loop I was really surprised just now by the unequal support across browsers. But the operator is supported as of nodejs 15 onward.

Comment: For the record:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment

Comment: I haven't seen anywhere else the usage I demonstrated above and I think this would deserve more attention. :( With that syntax one can easily and cleanly initialize arrays and maps on first assignment.

Comment: I found a suitable old question where I could elaborate on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944956/default-values-for-nested-javascript-hashes/66401897#66401897

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible to do with `Object.create`. It will not work for "non defined" properties. But for the ones that has been given a default value.

```
var defaults = {
    a: 'test1',
    b: 'test2'
};
```

Then when you create your properties object you do it with `Object.create`

```
properties = Object.create(defaults);
```

Now you will have two object where the first object is empty, but the prototype points to the `defaults` object. To test:

```
console.log('Unchanged', properties);
properties.a = 'updated';
console.log('Updated', properties);
console.log('Defaults', Object.getPrototypeOf(properties));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.withDefault = (defaultValue,o={}) => {
  return new Proxy(o, {
    get: (o, k) => (k in o) ? o[k] : defaultValue 
  });
}

o = Object.withDefault(42);
o.x  //=> 42

o.x = 10
o.x  //=> 10
o.xx //=> 42
```

Comment: So... using Proxies also means you lose out on all the nice Object methods now :(

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of the [Logical nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), you can now do something like this

```js
const obj = {}
obj.a ??= "default";
```

In the case where you have an empty list as the default value and want to push to it, you could do

```js
const obj = {}
(obj.a ??= []).push("some value")
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to take a defaults object and merge it with the target object.  The target object would override values in the defaults object.

jQuery has the `.extend()` method that does this.  jQuery is not needed however as there are vanilla JS implementations such as can be found here:

http://gomakethings.com/vanilla-javascript-version-of-jquery-extend/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to construct a copy of a given object with missing fields filled by default values, you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```
let a = {
    foo: "foo value",
    bar: "bar value"
};

let result = {
    foo: "default foo value",
    bar: "default bar value",
    bazz: "default bazz value",

    ... a
}
```

The input object should come after the defaults, so it will replace the defaults by the values of its properties if they are defined, but leave intact the default values of missing properties. So the result will be:

```
{
    foo: "foo value",
    bar: "bar value",
    bazz: "default bazz value"
}
```

Note that the default values will only appear for missing properties. If a property exists, but has a `null` or `undefined` value, it will **not** be replaced by a default value, so `null`-s and `undefined`-s will appear in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If using Node.js, you can use the popular [`object.defaults`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.defaults) library:

> #### Usage
>
> var defaults = require('object.defaults');
>
> ```
> var obj = {a: 'c'};
> defaults(obj, {a: 'bbb', d: 'c'});
> console.log(obj);
> //=> {a: 'c', d: 'c'}
> ```
>
> Or immutable defaulting:
>
> ```
> var defaults = require('object.defaults/immutable');
> var obj = {a: 'c'};
> var defaulted = defaults(obj, {a: 'bbb', d: 'c'});
> console.log(obj !== defaulted);
> //=> true
> ```