# Angular services with default values for non-existing attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Working on an Ionic application that performs both in Android and Windows.

There are services, such as Ionic's `$ionicLoading`, which we override functionality in order to work properly in windows:

```
angular.factory('$ionicLoading', function(){
    return {
        show: function (){...} // custom implementation
        hide: function (){...} // custom implementation
    }
});
```

But there are other services which we have to override only to not break the app.
In this cases it would be really useful to provide a service that won't do anything. For example:

```
angular.factory('$ionicExampleService', function(){
    return {
        *foo*: angular.noop // for operations
        *bar*: promise // returns promise
    }
});
```

> **Note:** I know that a better way of doing this would be with a service that chooses between Ionic's implementation or a made one, but this is just for the sake of learning.

**The ideal** would be going even further, it would be magnificent to be able to return something even more bulletproof. Something like a generic flexible services:

```
angular.factory('$ionicPopup', function(){
    return /*magic*/;
});

$ionicPopup.show({...}) // show was not defined
    .then(foo); // won't break and will execute foo()
```

It is possible?

Comment: This question has a very nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes

Comment: I expanded a bit on Sunny's answer to help it fit the situation. I also removed your -1 rating. -C§

Answer (score 4):

From what I understood you need to override implementation of existing services. You can do that with an angular service decorator.

> A service decorator intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it to override or modify the behaviour of the service. The object returned by the decorator may be the original service, or a new service object which replaces or wraps and delegates to the original service.

For more information you can check angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide). One simple example would be:

```
app.factory('someService', function () {
    return {
        method1: function () { return '1'; }
        method2: function () { return '2'; }
    };
});

app.decorator('someService', function ($delegate) {
    // NOTE: $delegate is the original service

    // override method2
    $delegate.method2 = function () { return '^2'; };

    // add new method
    $delegate.method3 = function () { return '3'; };

    return $delegate;
});

// usage
app.controller('SomeController', function(someService) {
    console.log(someService.method1());
    console.log(someService.method2());
    console.log(someService.method3());
});
```

EDIT: Question - How to override every method in the service?

```
var dummyMethod = angular.noop;

for(var prop in $delegate) {
    if (angular.isFunction($delegate[prop])) {
        $delegate[prop] = dummyMethod;
    }
}
```

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: The problem is that i want to override everymethod that `someService` has without know his implementation. Something like `$delate.everyMethod = function(){return 'hello world!'; };`

Answer (score 0):

Using an evaluation for each assignment based on an object property, similar to this:

```
myVar = myObj.myPropVar === undefined ? "default replacement" : myObj.myPropVar;
```

Basically you're using a check for if the property has been defined, substituting a default value if it hasn't, and assigning it if it has.

Alternatively, you can use a modified version of the global function in Sunny's linkback to define defaults for all those properties you might assume to be undefined at specific points in your code.

```
function getProperty(o, prop) {
    if (o[prop] !== undefined) return o[prop];
    else if(prop == "foo") return "default value for foo";
    else if(prop == "bar") return "default value for bar";
    /* etc */
    else return "default for missing prop";
}
```

Hope that helps,

C§

Answer (score -3):

use `var a = {};` to declare new variable.