# Set default value of JavaScript object member when null

Tags: javascript

I have following JavaScript object

```
myObject = {
    Fname: 'A',
    Mname: null,
    Lname: 'C',
    Email: 'AB@gmail.com',
    Address: null,
    Login: 'AB',
    Active: null
};
```

I want to set fields to some default value if it `null` so my resulting object should be like.

```
Object {
    Fname: "A",
    Mname: "",
    Lname: "C",
    Email: "AB@gmail.com",
    Address: "",
    Login: 'AB',
    Active: ""
}
```

Is there any fast way for doing that because in my case there are about 80 to 100 fields of object. And it takes too much time to check the fields one by one

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes

Comment: there are a lot of ways to do this, it would help if you show how you are using your objets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` and `forEach` as follow.

```js
myObject = {
  Fname: 'A',
  Mname: null,
  Lname: 'C',
  Email: 'AB@gmail.com',
  Address: null,
  Login: 'AB',
  Active: null
};

// Get array of keys of the object
// Loop over it
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(e) {

  // If value of the object member is `null` set it to `''` - empty string.
  if (myObject[e] === null)
    myObject[e] = '';
});

console.log(myObject);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myObject, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

---

You can also use `regex` with `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

```
myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject).replace(/:null/g, ':""'));
```

```js
var myObject = {
  Fname: 'A',
  Mname: null,
  Lname: 'C',
  Email: 'AB@gmail.com',
  Address: null,
  Login: 'AB',
  Active: null
};

myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject).replace(/:null/g, ':""'));

console.log(myObject);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myObject, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I personally would prefer if (myObject[e] === null) { myObject[e] = "" } so you're not doing pointless assignment operators.