# Simple JS AutoMock Possible?

Tags: javascript

Im not really getting into the details of WHY doing this as its needed.

Supose i have a simple object.

```
var obj = {};
```

Lets say i want to access a random property of that object

```
obj.randomProp
```

This is getting me undefined.
Now, would it be possible, for that obj.randomProp return me another empty object ( `{}` ) ?

Of course, with no property declaration as `obj.randomProp=123`. I was thinking on this to be dynamic, somehow like a `default property getter` as if everytime you try to get a property of this element, you will get a new empty object for it.

Is this possible in JS ?

Comment: Yes, with Proxies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value of javascript object attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes)

Comment: It is a duplicate so far, ive read about proxies now and its what im looking for, but i didnt managed to make a `infinite` proxy

Comment: What is infinite proxy?

Comment: If you want to return by default an object that does exactly the same thing as the original, just return a copy of the original.