# How do I set the default property of an object (object)?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I need to add new objects to the list (Filters.list)
* Filters.prop - is a default prop
* list items also have prop - list[name].prop (equal default prop)

Chage default *Filters.prop* -> [not] change item *list[name].prop*
Where is the mistake?

```js
function Filters() {
  this.prop = 'some';  
  this.list = { };
  
  this.add = function (name) {
    this.list[name] = {
      prop: this.prop,
    };
  }
} 
 
let attempt = new Filters();
attempt.add('first');
attempt.prop = 'other';

document.writeln(attempt.prop);
document.writeln(attempt.list['first'].prop);
```

After run snippet output: other some
But I need: other other

I thought the property would be saved by reference. But this is not so, it does not change. When I change *Filters.prop* I expected that too it will change *list[name].prop*

Comment: Please tell us the expected output? Your question lacks details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value of javascript object attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes)

Comment: You might want to use the ES6 classes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is that, as you noticed yourself, the value is passed the way you're doing it instead of the reference.

Thanks to [JavaScript get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), you can return the value of `prop` of the surrounding object within a function which behaves like an attribute.

```js
function Filters() {
  this.prop = 'some';  
  this.list = { };
  
  this.add = function(name) {
    let self = this;
    this.list[name] = {
      get prop() {
        return self.prop;
      },
    };
  }
}

let attempt = new Filters();
attempt.add('first');
attempt.prop = 'other';

document.writeln(attempt.prop)
document.writeln(attempt.list['first'].prop)
```

Side note: I use the variable `self` here because using `this.prop` within `get prop()` would reference the wrong object and hence cause a recursion.