# Is there a way to capture a variable access?

Tags: javascript

I am currently having a problem to which a potential solution is always returning something when trying to access an undefined property.

As an example consider this:

```js
const obj = {}
obj.myMethod() // will throw an error as obj.myMethod is undefined
populateObj(obj)
obj.myMethod() // will work now that myMethod is defined
```

It is not possible to set `obj.myMethod` to some default value beforehand as the names of the properties of `obj` are unknown (their names are determined by an external server). So I was thinking of having `obj` return some default method whenever accessing an undefined property. I am guessing that there is no way of doing this in javascript but thought I'd ask just in case.

Thanks in advance!

Note: I know I could introduce a `obj.get` method to return either a default value or the one set in `obj`, however I am trying to make this work with object destructuring.

Comment: try assigning with an empty function

Comment: It seems like the solution to this thread will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes

Comment: @User863 that won't work as the names of the properties of obj are unknown beforehand. I might have found a way to do this with proxies though, I have posted a link above^

Comment: "return some default method " -default method - how it should be ? Example pls

Comment: `obj = new Proxy({}, { get: () => () => {} });`

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks, I will try using Proxies :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default value of javascript object attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes)

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yes it does, thanks & have a great day