# Is it possible to define the get item of a javascript object as a function?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to define some class or object where I can do

```js
Foo['bar']
```

This get item call should call a function so that I can provide a default or some other logic based on the key. Similar to [python's `__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

```
const Foo = {
   __getitem__: key => {
     if (key in Foo.values) return Foo.values[key]
     // other logic
     return key
   }

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get should help you

Comment: You will need a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723887/402037