# javascript , how not return undefined , when I use Any property

Tags: javascript

```
let obj = {}
obj.name  // this is  undefined  
obj.age  // this is undefined
```

Now I want to return null, How I define obj, not use proxy ?

My js object has this method:

```
function xxx (key){
  if(key === 'name') return  null
  if(key === 'age') return 'hello age'
  return undefined
}
```

do not know property, but when use property not return undefined

Comment: Could you explain what problem your trying to solve here, eg. you could just have done `let obj = {name:null, age: 'hello age'}` and this would line up with your xxx function.

Answer (score 0):

Specify them as null when creating your object at first. For example:

```
const obj = {
   name : null,
   age : null
}
```

If you want to change the default value of Javascript object attributes,
[check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723887/16276455).